# Power Apps - How to change the format of the Rich text column to normal text of the Data Table object

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

Power Apps - How to change the format of the Rich text column to normal text of the Data Table object.

I have created a power app form and showing a data from a list using data table object in power apps.Currently Data shows html tag along with the data. I want to change the format of the Rich text column to normal text of the Data Table object. I cannot change the SharePoint column to single line text.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this on the settings of the field.
You must have your field in "Plain text"

[image]

It's not a problem of PowerApps, it's SharePoint, when you have a field (Multi Line of text) in rich text mode, SharePoint automaticaly save this data as HTML.

If you want to use the rich text, you can have a look at the powerApps Rich text contol : [Rich text editor control (experimental) in PowerApps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-richtexteditor)

Comment: Hey thanks but as mentioned above in question and as per requirement I shouldn't be changing that. User wants it as Rich text in SharePoint...
So this won't help...

Comment: thas why I show you the PowerApps control : Rich Text Editor. You need to remove the old text input and replace it with this controls.

Comment: User wants the column as Rich text and on power apps I cannot replace control....it is a data table control and there is no option to add control inside